# ng-change does not trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-change does not trigger my function anyhow,  here is the view;

```
            <div ng-controller="widgets.lunchMenu as vm">
                   <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm active">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option1" ng-model="vm.takeCount" ng-value="0" ng-change="vm.getLunchMenus()">@L("Today")
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option2" ng-model="vm.takeCount" ng-value="7" ng-change="vm.getLunchMenus()">@L("Week")
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option3" ng-model="vm.takeCount" ng-value="30" ng-change="vm.getLunchMenus()">@L("Month")
                    </label>
            </div>
```

here is the controller :

```
    (function () {
    appModule.controller('widgets.lunchMenu', [
    '$scope', 'abp.services.app.lunch',
    function ($scope, appService) {
        var vm = this;
        var today = new Date();
        var month = today.getMonth();

        vm.getLunchMenus = function () {
            appService.getLunchMenus({ month: month + 1, takeCount: vm.takeCount }).success(function (data) {
                vm.menus = data.items;
            });;
        };

        vm.getLunchMenus();
    }
]);
})();
```

any suggestion ? thanks for helping.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Suggestion: define `vm = $scope` or change your binding to `$scope.getLunchMenus()`.  Your HTML only interacts with `$scope` variables and functions.

Comment: @ryanyuyu the poster appears to be using the ControllerAs syntax (though the use of `vm` as the generic name for each controller is a bit problematic).  changing `vm` to point to `$scope` doesn't make sense.

Comment: AngularJS v1.4.1 is the version that i use.

Comment: Your minimal example works, see this : http://jsfiddle.net/rmmuoe5a/. There is probably an issue with your `appService`.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the `ng-change` directive to be able to see the `vm.getLunchMenus` function, it has to be on the `$scope`. So you'd need to do something along the lines of:

```
$scope.vm = this;
$scope.vm = function() { ... }
```

Then in your markup, you could do what you're doing with

```
ng-change="vm.getLunchMenus()"
```

---

Or you could just do something as simple as

```
$scope.getLunchMenus = function() { ... }
```

Then in the markup:

```
ng-change="getLunchmenus()"
```

Do completely remove the need for the `vm` variable, since `this` doesn't really mean anything to the directives (`ng-change`, etc.) in the markup.

Comment: The poster hasn't shown the full HTML code where the controller is defined, but they appear to be using the ControllerAs syntax, which is a valid way to structure the data; you are suggesting here that they abandon that syntax and go back to using `$scope` instead, which isn't likely to solve their core issue of the function not firing.

Comment: Claies is right. I'm using ControllerAs syntax which covers vm. Problem is something else.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not familiar with ControllerAs syntax.